# When returning a Mono from a ReactiveMongo repository does the database call start in the background?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-webflux, project-reactor, nonblocking

I am new to Spring WebFlux and would like to know what happens when a `Mono` is returned from a `ReactiveMongo` repository.

**Does the database call begin immediately after it being returned?**

For example:

```
public void serviceMethod() {
   var mono = reactiveMongoRepo.findItemById("123");
}
```

When the `Mono` is returned does the database call start instantly or **do I have to `subscrisbe` to the `Mono` to get the start the database call ?**

**What actually happens under the hood ?**

Comment: First the flow is built, when the initial call is made. Then it is executed when someone subscribes. Be sure you don't include any blocking calls during the build phase.

Comment: i recommend that you read the reactor documentation, especially the getting started section.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare your reactive code, its just what it is, a declaration. You are basically describing what you want your flow to look like when someone `subscribes`. This is called `assembly time` in reactor terminology.

When someone actually subscribes (for instance an external client) we enter what is called `subscription time`. The subscriber triggers a signal that is propagated up the stream with the purpose to find a `publisher`.

The `subscriber` basically asks in reverse up the chain (upstream), *"are you a publisher?"* the chain might answer *"no"* then the signal will be propagated again up the chain (upstream) asking *"are you a publisher?"* until it finds one. For instance, a database call, or a Flux, or a Mono etc. etc.

When it has found a `publisher` from there on, we’re in `execution time`. The data will start flowing through the pipeline (in the more natural top-to-bottom order, or upstream to downstream).

You can read more about it in the blog series [Flight of the flux](https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/06/flight-of-the-flux-1-assembly-vs-subscription) written by the reactor developer [Simon Baslé](https://spring.io/team/simonbasle) which is an excellent read to get to know a little bit more about the inner workings of the reactor library.

Answer (score 0):

No. Nothing happens until you, or more likely when using Spring WebFlux the framework subscribes to the chain.

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactive.subscribe

> In Reactor, when you write a Publisher chain, data does not start pumping into it by default. Instead, you create an abstract description of your asynchronous process (which can help with reusability and composition).

> By the act of subscribing, you tie the Publisher to a Subscriber, which triggers the flow of data in the whole chain. This is achieved internally by a single request signal from the Subscriber that is propagated upstream, all the way back to the source Publisher.